# Does containers nesting in XAML affect rendering performance?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, xaml

Does the rendering performance reduce seriously in case when WPF application's XAML contains a **lot** of nested `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `DockPanel` and other containers?

Comment: @SonerGönül Interested in fundamental answer (for example, what if CLR optimizes that code in a certain way)

Comment: @SonerGönül stop trolling SO and contribute something useful besides reformatting every question under the sun. This issue is complex and perf testing it is not a trivial operation.

Comment: @Gusdor He answers multiple questions a day. You can check his activity. And his rep shows he doesn't "[reformat] every question under the sun". This is definitely testable, and it's probably best if it's tested instead of left to theory.

Comment: @MillieSmith I did not deny it was testable. Lets place our weighting on quality of answer, not quantity, shall we?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF uses `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods inorder to render UIElements. `MeasureOverride` measure the UIElements width and size based on the Parent controls Width and Size. `ArrangeOVerride` method will arrange the UIElements at runtime based on these measures. These methods are optimized for faster performance and should not cause any rendering performance issue.

**But there should be a capacity where these methods can handle UIElements within a minimal time. If this limit exceeds then there should be performance issue.**

eg: Suppose a bike can carry 2 person. if 5 persons overloaded what will happen :)

Jet Brains .Trace is a tool to analyze the performance issue which will helps to see these two methods

Comment: This answers seems to hinge upon 'if you make it too slow, it will be slow' logic.

Answer (score 3):

Really the answer is simply "yes". More of anything will use more processor time. *SURPRISE!*

In the case of WPF, elements are arranged into a hierarchical *scene graph*. Adding levels of depth to this graph will slow your application more than adding siblings to existing elements. You should always strive to keep the depth the graph low. Consider using `Grid` instead of nesting `StackPanel`s.

So why is depth more important than raw element count? Well, depth generally implies;

1. layout dependency - if a parent is re-sized a child is likely to be re-rendered.
2. occlusion - if 2 elements overlap, invalidating one will often invalidate the other.
3. recursion - most graph operations are *CPU bound* - they depend entirely on CPU speed and have no dedicated hardware support (the renderer uses your graphics chip where possible). Cycling through levels of the graph for resources and layout updates is expensive.

Concerning occlusion, the `BitmapCache` class can help greatly!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a very complex UI, with lots of nested objects and DataTemplate with lot of elements, you can impact seriously the performance of the App, because the bigger the UI Tree, the bigger it will take to render, and if the framework cannot render in 30FPS you will start to see performance drops. You should use the most lightweight panels you need in order to avoid extra logic you wonn't need. Here are  some performance tips in order to make you App faster:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good link, epsecially regarding choosing your `Panel`s carefully. Nobody else has noted that not all panels are equal. `Grid` is versatile, but its rendering logic is more involved. If you don't really need to use it, don't!

Comment: Exactly, for example in Winwodws 8.1 the all the logic relating the selection of an ítem has been deleted in order to make the ItemContainers thiner and faster. I encourage you to read this post about improving performance in Windows 8.1 XAML apps because it is also applicable to WPF apps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994641.aspx Hope it helps!